# interpolate time series of multiple tables

Tags: r, time-series

I want to lineary interpolate the colums "date", "time" and "temp" from an original 5 to an 1 second interval for multiple tables in R:

old:

```
date         time     temp
1 22.05.11 16:00:00 23.653 
2 22.05.11 16:00:05 23.541 
...
```

new:

```
date         time     temp 
1 22.05.11 16:00:00 23.653 
2 22.05.11 16:00:01 23.631 
3 22.05.11 16:00:02 23.609
...
```

How can I do this?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is easy to do with `na.approx` and/or `na.spline` from the `zoo` package.

```
# example data
set.seed(21)
z <- zoo(23+runif(10), seq(Sys.time(),length.out=10,by=5))
# merge your data with an empty zoo object that has an index value for
# every period you're interested in.
y <- merge(z, zoo(order.by=seq(start(z), end(z), by=1)))
xa <- na.approx(y)
xs <- na.spline(y)
plot(merge(xa,xs))

# To convert your existing data.frame to a zoo object:
z <- zoo(Data$temp,
  as.POSIXct(paste(Data$date, Data$time), format="%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S"))
y <- merge(z, zoo(order.by=seq(start(z), end(z), by=1)))
xa <- na.approx(y)
xs <- na.spline(y)
plot(merge(xa,xs))
# Convert back to data.frame
dfxa <- data.frame(date=format(index(xa), "%d.%m.%y"),
                   time=format(index(xa), "%H:%M:%S"), temp=coredata(xa))
```

Comment: z is a value here, while my data is a table, so i´m not quite sure how to implement that here...

Comment: I added code to show you how to convert your data.frame (I doubt you're really using a `table` object) to a zoo object.